# Docker - "EPERM: operation not permitted

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

hope someone can help me, been struggling with that for some days now.

So, everything works fine inside my docker container.
When I use `docker exec -it main sh`, creating a new directory I am able to perform git clone and other commands without any problem. I've been able to run `yarn` inside this app folder, and the packages were successfully installed.

But whenever I run docker-compose up --build, it builds and pull all files correctly, but gives me `"EPERM: operation not permitted` for any command inside the project folder.

This is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
    version: "3"

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: nginx_proxy
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
    depends_on:
      - main
    networks:
      - internal-docker-network

  main:
    build: ./main
    container_name: main
    restart: unless-stopped
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    command: /start_app.sh dev_ubuntu main
    depends_on:
      - main_db
      - rabbitmq
    ports:
      - "8887:8887"
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=dev_ubuntu
      - NODE_PATH=/home/myprojectfolder/My_Project_Directory/app/modules
    volumes:
      - ./src/:/home/myprojectfolder/My_Project_Directory
      - ./main/start_app.sh:/start_app.sh
      - ~/.ssh/id_rsa:/root/.ssh/id_rsa:ro
      - ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub:/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub:ro
    networks:
      - internal-docker-network
```

This is my start_app.sh file:

```
export NODE_PATH=/home/myprojectfolder/My_Project_Directory/app/modules/
export NODE_ENV=$2

cd /home/myprojectfolder/My_Project_Directory/app/

yarn

cp ./modules/client_cw_globals_base/index.json ./modules/client_cw_globals.json

gulp main --node_env $2
```

Would appreciate any kind of help, I am really lost in here.
Thanks!

Comment: the ./src path in volumes, is where the git clone was made on my local.

Comment: Without a Dockerfile and any other dependencies, we cannot reproduce this. Please see [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

It happens that my cloned src folder, for some reason, was the reason of the not permitted errors.
I don't know why, but cloning it manually solved the problem.
I'm using mac, by the way.